# How to isolate known properties in an intersection of a generic type and a non-generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have an HOC that takes a `withPaper` prop but does not pass it to the component it will render.

```
import React, { ComponentType, FC } from "react";
import { Paper } from "@material-ui/core";

interface WithOptionalPaperProps {
  withPaper?: boolean;
}

export const withOptionalPaper = <Props extends object>() => (
  Component: ComponentType<Props>
) => ({ withPaper, ...otherProps }: Props & WithOptionalPaperProps) => {
  if (withPaper) {
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Component {...otherProps as Props} />
      </Paper>
    );
  }
  return <Component {...otherProps as Props} />;
};

// Code below shows how the code above will be used.

interface NonPaperedComponentProps {
  text: string;
  className: string;
}

const NonPaperedComponent: FC<NonPaperedComponentProps> = props => {
  return <h1 className={props.className}>{props.text}</h1>;
};

// Code will be used like an HOC.
// 'withPaper' prop can be optionally added to wrap the underlying component in 'Paper'
const OptionalPaperedComponent = withOptionalPaper<NonPaperedComponentProps>()(
  NonPaperedComponent
);

// All props except 'withPaper' should be passed to 'NonPaperedComponent'
const renderedComponent = (
  <OptionalPaperedComponent withPaper className="Hello" text="Hello There" />
);
```

I have removed the errors by type casting with `otherProps as Props`. Without them it produces the error `'Props' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'`

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-shamir-z2098?file=/src/App.tsx:399-400

I would have assumed that since I have destructured and isolated the known properties from `Props & WithOptionalPaperProps` the types would look like this:

```
{
    withPaper, // type 'WithOptionalPaperProps["withPaper"]'
    ...otherProps // type 'Props'
}
```

How do I make it that the Component the `withOptionalPaper` returns with a `withPaper` prop without passing it to its children but still passing all the other props?

Comment: How do you want to call `withOptionalPaper`? You've used an initial lower case letter, making me think you don't intend to directly use it as a component. That being the case, I think the simplest solution would be two arguments: `props: Props, withPaper?: boolean`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Edited the codesandbox to show how it will be used.

Comment: FWIW, an alternative approach, but not an answer to the question: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-ishizaka-n22rh?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation in how de-structured rest objects are types. For a long type TS did not even allow de-structuring of generic type parameters. In version 3.2 the ability to use rest variables with generic type parameters was added ([PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28312)) but the rest variable is typed as `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "other" | "props">>`, or equivalently `Omit<T, "other" | "props">`. The use of the conditional type `Exclude` will work fine for the consumers of this function if `T` is fully resolved (ie not a generic type parameter) but inside the function, typescript can't really reason about the type that contains the `Exclude`. This is just a limitation of how conditional types work. You are excluding from `T`, but since `T` is not known, ts will defer the evaluation of the conditional type. This means that `T` will not be assignable to `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "other" | "props">>`

We can use a type assertion as you have, and this is what I have recommended in the past. Type assertions should be avoided, but they are there to help out when you (ie the developer) have more information than the compiler. This is one of those cases.

For a better workaround we could use a trick. While `Omit<T, "props">` is not assignable to `T` it is assignable to itself. So we can type the component props as `Props | Omit<Props, "withPaper">`. Since `Props` and `Omit<Props, "withPaper">` are essentially the same type, this will not matter much, but it will let the compiler assign the rest object to the component props.

```
export const withOptionalPaper = <Props extends object>(
  Component: ComponentType<Props | Omit<Props & WithOptionalPaperProps, keyof WithOptionalPaperProps>>
) => ( {withPaper, ...otherProps }: Props & WithOptionalPaperProps) => {
  if (withPaper) {
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Component {...otherProps} />
      </Paper>
    );
  }
  return <Component {...otherProps } />;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtoROBAHZIUwAqAnmEnAL5wBmUZcARFKhh4BuALAAoUJFi44ABRRMorDlxC8AAiBQwkUYCgA2AWgCuwAPRpoSYePHAau9umYB1YDAAWAeTAxglIbyirJcYADOuOJwcADuHp7BugD8AFxwAEYQEAaoFKJiLHZiSAAeUvBWFOHw8V6+-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-LcgkIjMU4InmwkimqxRfgAglGqGYmUGZ+JxSGKChnoQCYBgkf+YB7kBZGcTJihyUsIo8WIfbwPwdH8CO8lse0cx8h0AmEkJdlsbpui7peB6tDwEEuq6PCkf0EVRVG5G0FK-CxXKYJCEAA)

Comment: Now *that* is why I sent you this question on Twitter. :-D That is just clever as hell. I'd probably just use the type assertion in this case, but what a neat way to avoid it.

Comment: Is it possible to use this workaround when the HOC also applies props to the composed component? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884#:~:text=HOC%20applies%20props%20to%20composed%20component%20and%20receives%20its%20own%20props

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh I adapted the solution for the use case you show on GH. Not sure if it works in any case, but for that specific case it works.